# Angular ui-router resolve service halting route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Attempting to get ui-router to resolve the Authentication service before I allow the switch into that state.

unfortunately it continues to evade me, with angular hanging whenever I inject a service that is not part of angular.

I know that I can't inject a service into .config, but surely I should be able to do it just before the controller is loaded?

here's a cut down version of the code:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

// For any unmatched url, redirect to state:home
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
        resolve: {
            isAuthorised: ['$log', '$q', 'Auth', function ($log, $q, auth) {
                var q = $q.defer();
                $log.debug("checking if authorised..."); //this doesn't show
                if (auth.whatever()) {
                    q.resolve(true);
                } else {
                    q.reject(false);
                }

                return q.promise;
            }]
        },
        controller: "DefaultCtrl"
    });
}]);
```

So the controller never actually gets instantiated... there are no errors in the console.

The same happens if I type any random string in as the service name... so my best guess is that it can't find it? But all other areas of the app can...

I have spent a while researching this and I'm pretty sure I should be able to accomplish this somehow.

any help would be most appreciated.

Grant.

### Edit

Thanks **Chris T** for the Plunkr! I am closing in on the issue, I added your console logs and I'm getting the following error:

```
Start:   {} -> home{}

Error:   {} -> home{} ReferenceError: $window is not defined {stack: "ReferenceError: $window is not defined↵    at a (h…pm/planitmoney/claw/dist/js/bower.min.js:815:112)", message: "$window is not defined"}
```

That bower.min.js file is just angular followed by UI router.. I'm going to do some more checking. Thanks again.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/aeEt4ddUYMM3xRi8M38T?p=preview

Comment: Thanks man - I updated the question to reflect what I've learned from your Plunkr. Cheers bro.

Comment: Try without minifying.  Search the code for $window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thanks again to Chris T** who created the Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/aeEt4ddUYMM3xRi8M38T?p=preview
which helped solve the issue.

I copied the console logs he has in there over to my application:

```
// Adds state change hooks; logs to console.
app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
$rootScope.$state = $state;
function message(to, toP, from, fromP) { return from.name  + angular.toJson(fromP) + " -> " +     to.name + angular.toJson(toP); }
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP) { console.log("Start:   " + message(to, toP, from, fromP)); });
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP) { console.log("Success: " + message(to, toP, from, fromP)); });
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP, err) {     console.log("Error:   " + message(to, toP, from, fromP), err); });
});
```

where I immediately noticed the error:

```
Start:   {} -> home{}

Error:   {} -> home{} ReferenceError: $window is not defined {stack: "ReferenceError: $window is not defined↵    at a (h…pm/planitmoney/claw/dist/js/bower.min.js:815:112)", message: "$window is not defined"}
```

digging a little deeper I traced the error to what was actually throwing it and it was fixed minutes later.

The service that I was attempting to resolve also called in some dependencies of its own. Unknown to me there was a missing $window injection in one of these services.

**The Error did not show up in the console**
I guess that it may have been because of the unique way in which it was accessed (using ui-routers resolve) Either that or my use of Raven in the application has thrown it somewhere that I didnt see it.

I hope this helps someone else get to the bottom of any issue.

Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar setup that checks localStorage for an token and resolves the promise.

Check the following example:

```
var requireUser = { User: [ "$location", "$rootScope", "$q", "API", "Session",
    function ( $location, $rootScope, $q, API, Session )
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

            if( Session.get.authToken() )
            {
                if( Session.get.user() )
                {
                    deferred.resolve( $rootScope.user );
                }
                else
                {
                    $location.path( "/login" );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                deferred.reject( "No user token" );
                $location.path( "/login" );
            }

        return deferred.promise;

    } ] };

$routeProvider
    .when( "/users", { templateUrl: "/build/templates/users.html", controller: "UsersCtrl", resolve: requireUser, active: "users" } )
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I am using ui-router ($stateProvider.state(...)) but resolve should operate the same way ... after continued tinkering I am still no closer to resolving this... get it ? bad joke.... ;)

Comment: should the UrlRouterProvider.otherwise function be after the state provider? Not sure if it will check the route first and fall back to `/` since that will run before your state is set.

Comment: even with that line at the bottom or even commented out entirely, I'm still running into the same issues :/

Comment: Are you able to set a breakpoint on `isAuthorised` and make sure it's being ran? Maybe step through it if you can. I can't tell if it's being invoked or not.

Comment: I can't add a breakpoint at the moment due to the fact that I am accessing the development machine in a VM and using chrome on the host system, the guest just grinds to a hault opening webstorm and chrome and everything else I have running. I'll be able to check later when I boot up Debian natively. I have this set up so that my laptop can drive 4 screens at work :/

Comment: LOL Wow, that's an intense setup! Hope you can figure it out :}